# How do you explain type forwarding in simple terms?

Tags: c#, .net

I am preparing for MCTS 70-536, after reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx) article. I am not 100% sure I understand the concept of typeforwarding. I find the steps given in the article even more confusing. Whats the deal if I am copying the sourcecode of type to be forwarded and recompiling it. What happens with old dll and the client ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type forwarding allows you to relocate a type between assemblies. So originally it is `TypeA` in `AssemblyA`. By applying type-forwarding, you can end with `TypeA` in `AssemblyB`.

The subtlety is the *code that is already compiled* doesn't see the change - they ask for the type in `AssemblyA`, and the runtime silently gives them the type from `AssemblyB`. This is very important if you have existing code.

However; *new* code cannot be recompiled referencing `TypeA` without you referencing `AssemblyB`.

So:

- old clients don't need to be recompiled
- however, you do need to rebuild both `AssemblyA` and `AssemblyB` in the above example
- new code (or any recompiled code) must now reference `AssemblyB` (the new one)

Comment: I read this on another website.  There seems to be some benefits using this.  However, one poster commented that VB.NET uses type forwarding and that it's a major issue if you are doing financial calculations).  Since I have no way to contact this user, I'm curious to know if you would know why?

Comment: How odd. I can think of no *direct* relationship between type-forwarding and financial calculations. I wonder if there is some subtle difference in what they mean... VB6, for example, performs a different type of type-forwarding re how it handles COM interfaces etc (when you add a method), but again; I see no direct relation to financials.