# How to re-export types from a referenced .NET assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, architecture, dependencies

We have a big .NET project consisting of many modules, which are implemented as Visual Studio library projects and compiled into respective assemblies (DLLs).

We have a layered architecture and we manage dependencies between the modules / layers by setting references between the Visual Studio projects / assemblies. This allows us to separate APIs/SPIs from the implementations, and keep distinct layers separated, thus effectively enforcing the constraints of our architecture.

However, simetimes we wish we could (transitively) re-export the types imported in one assembly to any further assembly which has a reference to the importing assembly.

For example, suppose a type `T` is defined in assembly `A`, assembly `B` references `A`, and assembly `C` references `B`, like this:

```
A <-- B <-- C
```

We would like to 'see' the type `T` in assembly `C`, without explicitly setting the reference to `A` in the assembly `C`. We would like to somehow *re-export* the reference to `A` in `B` instead.

Is it possible?

P. S. Why do we want to do this? Because some types are used throuout the application (think of utility/helper classes or common interfaces) and it would be annoying to duplicate the references in every project which depends on these types. Furthermore, when we refactor our code and move these around, we get lots of error messages because of missing references.

**EDIT**

To clarify, here is a simple diagram.

[image]

Not only does `Consumer B` depend on `B`, but also on `A`, since `B` extends `A`. However, if `A` is defined in a different assembly than the assembly of `B`, then we also **must** add a reference to the assembly of `A` (the same applies to providers). But there is no actual **need** to add this reference, since the dependency on `A` **follows** from the fact that we depend on `B` and `B` extends `A`. What we really need is to somehow *re-export* the dependency of `B` on `A`.

How can this scenario emerge? Suppose there was only one interface `B` and you decided to extract common interface (`A`) from `B` and place it in a separate assembly such that some other modules can reuse the new interface without adding the dependency on the original interface. And there you go: now you'll have to add a reference to the new assembly everywhere `B` was used before.

Comment: I'd say you better have a single Core or Helper assembly that contains all " types are used throughout the application" referenced by all other assemblies. Getting all other VS projects referencing a single one is a clean and easy to follow constraint, much cleaner than trying to propagate common types usage through TypeForwardedToAttribute.

Comment: We started with this approach, but eventually found out that it did not scale well: it resulted in one fat Core module containing many classes for all various purposes in one place - an all-or-nothing solution so to say. The problem was, of course, that not all classes are used throughout the application equally: some parts of the application requires these classes and some other part requires different ones. Putting them all in one place is not reasonable.

Comment: "The problem was, of course, that not all classes are used throughout the application equally"   Ok you didn't mention that :) It looks like you are trying to find a trick to escape a proper code structure refactoring. Such refactoring would define a set of low-level core components, on which high-level layers would depend.  "some parts of the application requires these classes and some other part requires different ones." It looks like it is a good start to define groups of classes that will become each a low-level component.

Comment: We don't really want to escape refactoring, we only want to find a way to make it less painful. :)

Comment: Despite your new Edit, I don't think what you need is a way to implicitly reference 'base' assemblies. I once wrote a blog post about how we restructured our code base, and it appeared to be cheaper than expected as long as you touch only the code structure and not the method bodies. Hope this helps: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing/

Comment: Great post! :) Interestingly enough, we have considered what you call *re-structuring* the 'true' form of refactoring (the other one being not worth mentioning). But you are right, it makes great sense to distinguish the two. Anyway, perhaps the problem is not that we can't re-export dependencies, but rather that the tools we are using don't do their job as good as we'd liked them to. If, for example, we could extract the common interface to a different assembly and the IDE would adjust the projects to reference the new assembly automatically, that would be just fine. But it doesn't.

Comment: @proskor: Did you consider [the solution I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745249/class-c-from-assembly-a1-implements-interface-from-assembly-a2-when-using-c-ne?noredirect=1#comment27153308_7745249)? Basically, to avoid referencing the assembly where the class/interface is defined, add a link to its source file it in the project which needs it.

Comment: @dario_ramos I appreciate your help, but honestly, I think this would only make it worse: instead of adding a reference to the whole project I would need to include *every* required file from that project to make it work.

Comment: That's true, it worked for me because I had just one interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an attribute on assemblies in .net where you can tell an assembly that the type it is expecting to be there, would be in another.

```
[assembly:TypeForwardedToAttribute(typeof(Example))]
```

Sounds like a usage of `Type Forwarding` to me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx

see also [How do you explain type forwarding in simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736968/how-do-you-explain-type-forwarding-in-simple-terms)

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out. I am not sure whether this is really what we need (we defenitely do not want to state which types are located in which assemblies), but it's a start. ;-)