# Can a type be "passed through" or exported from an assembly, through another?

Tags: c#, .net, types, .net-assembly

I have pretty much exactly the same question as the one linked below, but that user accepted an answer that is not what I'm working for.

[How to re-export types from a referenced .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466069/how-to-re-export-types-from-a-referenced-net-assembly)

Essentially, I am wondering if C# is capable of this scenario:

Let's say I have a project called "Proj1" in which I have a reference to a third-party assembly, say, a NuGet package called X.  Proj1 works extensively with types in X.  Now let's say I have a project, "Proj2," which references Proj1, and needs to use a couple of the types defined in X, but should not have access to anything else in X.  Is there any easy way, within Proj1, to state that a type from X should be exported for use by any project referencing Proj1, such that, what Proj1 sees as type `X.TheirNamespace.SomeType` can be seen in Proj2 as type `Proj1.MyNameSpace.SomeType`?

I realize I could write a verbatim, 1:1 wrapper, in Proj1, of the type needed from X, and I may do just that, but I figured I should find out if C# has a simple, declarative way to do this which wouldn't require writing all that wrapper code.

Comment: Why not let Proj2 just reference the 3rd party library?  But yeah, that or a wrapper class as I don't know of any way to do what you're talking about.

Comment: @juharr Allowing the direct reference is an option.  I started digging this export idea after doing some work on TypeScript modules.  Whenever any of my projects reference types from X, it will be in conjunction with using services from Proj1, so for cleanliness and information hiding (X is large and elaborate), I figured if C# supported an export-like technique, then it might be cleaner.  I, too, can't think of any way to do it, and I'm guessing there isn't one, but I've been surprised before by the things the big brains at SO come up with, so I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: Referencing the 3rd party from Proj2 doesn't seem like a good idea to me: you are introducing an extra dependency for proj 2.
Using the wrapper, and thus hiding 'X' from Proj1 ensures you can easily switch to another 3rd part library (or another version of teh same one) without any need to change proj2.