# How to rename a class without breaking consuming code in c#

Tags: .net, refactoring

I seem to remember something about this back when I studied for one of the Microsoft exams many, many fortnights ago although maybe I'm just misremembering.

Seems like if you wanted to rename a class in a dll, but you can't update the consuming code, you could put some attribute over the class or something that would allow the old class name to redirect to the new one.

I could just totally be making that up because I can't seem to find anything on google about it but figured it was worth asking just in case my search skills aren't as good as I like to believe they are.

Comment: I don't think this exists, there is an enhancement open currently about it: [Discussion: internal aliases #259](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/259#issuecomment-286110157): *Whatever we do here, I hope we don't block a future CLR improvement where I can declare a runtime type alias, enabling me to change the name of a type without breaking source or binary compatibility.*  Maybe you were thinking of [type forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/736968)?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime

Comment: Yes you're right that's exactly what I was thinking of. Too bad :/